# gmail api body recognition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I get messages from gmail by api. I have this code and it works.

```
for message in messages:
    # Get the message from its id
    msg = service.users().messages().get(userId="me", id=message["id"], format="full").execute()

    # Use try-except to avoid any errors
    try:
        # Get the headers of the message
        headers = msg["payload"]["headers"]

        # Initialize variables for the Subject, Sender Email, Date, In-Reply-To, and References headers
        subject = None
        sender = None
        date = None
        in_reply_to = None
        references = None

        # Look for Subject, Sender Email, and Date in the headers
        for d in headers:
            if d["name"] == "Subject":
                subject = d["value"]
            if d["name"] == "From":
                sender = d["value"]
            if d["name"] == "Date":
                date = d["value"]
            if d["name"] == "In-Reply-To":
                in_reply_to = d["value"]
            if d["name"] == "References":
                references = d["value"]

        # Initialize an empty string called body
        body = ""

        # Loop through the parts of the message body
        for part in msg["payload"]["parts"]:
            # If the part is of type 'text/plain' or 'text/html'
            if part["mimeType"] in ["text/plain", "text/html"]:
                # Decode the data of the part and get the text
                msg_data = part["body"]["data"] # bytes
                msg_text = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(msg_data).decode()
                # Append the text to the body string
                body += msg_text
        #get the snippet
        snippet = msg['snippet']

        # Get the message's data
        if 'parts' in msg['payload']:
            if msg['payload']['parts'][0]['mimeType'] == 'multipart/alternative':
                message_raw = msg['payload']['parts'][0]['parts'][0]['body']['data']
            else:
                message_raw = msg['payload']['parts'][0]['body']['data']
        else:
            message_raw = msg['payload']['body']['data']

        # Decode the data from base64
        msg_text = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message_raw).decode()

        # Parse the message with BeautifulSoup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(msg_text, 'html.parser')

        # Append the subject, sender, body, and date to the rows list
        rows.append((subject, sender, body, date, message["id"], snippet, in_reply_to, references, soup))

    except:
        pass

# Create a DataFrame with the rows and set the column names
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["subject", "sender", "body", "date", "id", 'snippet', 'in_reply_to','references', 'soup'])
```

I have 2 problems:

1. some messages are with empty body (column body), but if i parse them with bs4 there are not. But bs4 parse body not goog and I have a lot of extra symbols like '[\r\n\r\n ...  ... \r\n [\n]]'.
2. if I add code after

## Decode the data from base64

```
    msg_text = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message_raw).decode()

    # Parse the message with BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(msg_text, 'html.parser')

    # Use the prettify() method to add indentation and line breaks
    b_soup = soup.prettify()

    # Use the get_text() method to remove tags
    b_soup = soup.get_text()

    # Use regular expressions to remove unwanted characters
    b_soup = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', soup)
    # Append the subject, sender, body, and date to the rows list


    rows.append((subject, sender, body, date, message["id"], snippet, soup, b_soup))
```

to make beatiful soup I get empty df.

I try to get gmail api enails and parse them.